# NASM error: invalid operand type when updating the edi register

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a code in assembly which builds 2 byte lists by some conditions that are not important. The thing is that I have to modify 2 lists at the same time, so I put the addresses of the lists in `edi` one at a time. The problem arises when a loop is made and I want to generate the next member of the lists. I tried putting the address of the specific list starting with the element to be modified by writing `mov edi, s1+bx`, where I increment `bx` with every loop but I get the error `invalid operand type`. Any idea why or is there a better alternative to doing this?

Comment: Both operands to `mov` have to be the same size, and `mov` can't do math.  Use `add edi, 2` to increment the pointer, or use `[edi + ebx + s1]` as the addressing mode for accessing memory in whatever other instruction you're using.  (Figure out whether you're using 2-byte addresses or 4-byte.  You almost always want the same bitness as whatever mode you're in, so 32-bit addresses in 32-bit code, regardless of 8, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit data.)

Comment: Check Intel's manual, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov

Comment: Apparently the address was a double word so I put `ebx` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.